# Linux without bash

Tags: shell, distribution-choice

I'm not new in Linux world but I never liked Bash. Generally for me programming is an art and I'm very sensitive to the language syntax. When I have to work with bash, it feels like I'm writing in Stone Age people language.

Maybe Fish is not perfect shell, but it is a way better than Bash and I want to switch to it completely, but something tells me that removing Bash from the system is not a great idea.

So I decided to ask this crazy question, even though I have little faith that anyone will have an answer - is there existed some usable Linux distro that have no bash out of the box?

Comment: I don't think you'll find distribution without `bash`.

If you don't like bash, just switch your own shell to `fish` and you'll never use  `bash` again

Comment: Bash is a POSIX-compliant shell. Fish is not. Using Fish as your default `/bin/sh` therefore makes you incompliant to the POSIX standard, which means many programs won't work. If you just really want to avoid Bash, there is e.g. Alpine Linux that uses the alternative shell Ash as its default `/bin/sh`, but I doubt you would find it any more fun than Bash since being a POSIX compliant shell means looking more or less like Bash does. I would advice you to not worry about the default shell so much and just write programs in whatever language you want.

Comment: I suggest that you keep `bash` because you probably need some tool that relies not it. You can select another program to be your interactive shell and use that shell for your own scripts.

Comment: over 99% of Linux-based systems have neither bash nor zsh nor fish. Android is the most well known example.

Comment: Why would you have to work with Bash even if it's installed? And even more so, why would you have to do anything that amounts to "programming" with Bash even if it's installed _and_ even if you used it as your interactive shell?

Comment: +1, I don't see how this question doesn't comply with [ask].

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, the question there is [asking for a software (distribution) recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed) though, and any answers would be just lists of distributions that comply with the requirement (or they'd need to be nonexistence proofs which is also problematic). Before the post gets to the question, it's [also soapboxing (ranting) a personal opinion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (not really long enough for a good rant, but all the same).

Comment: And of course the tool tip for the downvote button also has includes the _"or [is] not useful"_ part.

Comment: @ilkkachu fair enough. I see some nuances here tough, the "rant" seems to me OP's explaining the *why*, wich can be useful to answer the question properly. The asking for software distribution doesn't prevent to answer the question properly either, as shown below. Being OP a new contributor plays some weight in my considerations. But just my opinion of course.

Comment: @ilkkachu because I prefer to have only one program in the system for any particular purpose. I have one browser, one audio player, one video player, one text editor and I want to have only one favorite shell which is not bash.

Comment: @luarocks, are you also going to remove all scripting language interpreters except your favourite one? What are you going to do if one utility you need relies on awk and another is implemented in Perl?

Comment: @ilkkachu of course, I keep dependencies, but I prefer not to have them. That's why I'm asking if there's a system that doesn't depend on bash. And I am looking for a yes or no answer, not a criticism.

Comment: @luarocks, like I said in the earlier comment, your question also reads as, hmm..., promoting a rather strong opinion. Of course you're free to go looking for such a distribution. But in case you were interested in getting something done, my suggestion would be to just not use that program and ignore its existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from changing your shell and forgetting about bash existence altogether.

```bsh
chsh --shell /usr/bin/fish
# or
usermod --shell /usr/bin/fish luarocks
```

It looks like you don't like its presence in principle but there could be many things in life which we don't like yet manage to disregard without going mad.

AFAIK there are no major well-supported distros with a large audience which don't use bash. If you really want to deal with less supported ones, you could even use the ones which come with `busybox`.

Comment: Make sure that the actual path to `fish` (`/usr/bin/fish`, not `/user/bin/fish`) is listed in `/etc/shells` or some tools will fail with `not a valid shell`.

Answer (score 0):

Many of applications have scripts installed in /usr subdirectories so if you remove bash none of them will continue to work properly, just don't remove it, and don't use bash as a your profile shell, using ksh or any other shell as default one for your user-land level default shell.

I don't think there are linux distros without bash, until even very light distros deliver at least bash/sh/ksh/csh and few others from scratch.